Answer deletion
I posted an answer to a question, but my answer was promptly deleted, apparently because I didn't cite my source. I didn't cite my source because my answer came directly from my own working paper on the subject, a working paper which no one could have access to but myself.  Maybe the problem occurred because my posted answer was an image I copied from my source document and pasted  in,  so the reader might have thought I had pasted in something from some other published work. In the future How can I avoid this problem? Would  specifically asserting that what I paste is mine alone be sufficient?

That is easy to assert and unfortunately not everyone on the internet is trustworthy. A picture is also hard to search for. I recommend you copy the source of your document in the answer box and post it directly to this site. I actually believe you did somewhere else. I also recommend merging your users into 1. I had to dig to find your other username which posted the question.

I didn't even know I had 2 usernames! I think jtwspoon is one, don't know the other.

The one you’re using right now ;) Edit: Seems fixed now :)
